Getting Module Not Found Exception while running Test with Playwright Java
I am running Playwright test with Junit and Java the test is running fine and finished as well but i am getting Module not found error when the test is finished not sure why
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144
const err = new Error(message);
         ^

Error: Cannot find module './../../package.json'
Require stack:

C:\Users\P741348d\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-11327499370590347457\package\lib\utils\userAgent.js
C:\Users\P741348d\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-11327499370590347457\package\lib\utils\index.js
C:\Users\P741348d\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-11327499370590347457\package\lib\cli\programWithTestStub.js
C:\Users\P741348d\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-11327499370590347457\package\cli.js


Please share a [mcve]--code, packages, environment and commands you're running to reproduce the problem. Thanks.
